# Pointing a laser to a mirror on the moon in spite of refraction by earth's atmosphere

Tags: laser, refraction, geometric-optics

I was reading that the Apollo missions left a laser reflector (Mirror) on the moon for scientific use. Having read some of the controversy here and elsewhere about lasers being affected by refraction etc, I was wondering how a laser beam fired from Earth could find and successfully reach such a mirror?

Comment: It is more a technical question. With a telescope and dynamical trecking with motors you are able to follow stars much more far away from the earth. Why do your think that a laser could not dynamical be directed on to a mirror on the moon?

Answer (score 4):

You assume that a laser beam is a single, fine line—as if it would project one tiny, millimeter-wide red dot.

But all practical lasers produce divergent beams. You can arbitrarily narrow the beam by shining it out through a telescope, but I'm pretty sure that the narrowest beam we can practically generate still will illuminate many square miles of the lunar surface. The Moon is, after all, a quarter of a million miles away.

Meanwhile, a telescope observing that same patch of lunar surface only needs to see a single bright dot, anywhere in its field of view, that correlates with the timing of the laser pulses and/or the wavelength to confirm the presence of the reflector.*

---

* And also, of course, to fulfill its *intended* purpose, which was to obtain high-precision measurements of the distance to the Moon.

Comment: "You can arbitrarily narrow the beam by shining it out through " - a *sufficiently wide* telescope. This is a real, practical limitation, and it makes claims of "arbitrary" narrowing of the beam pretty hollow.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, OK, maybe I did not express my thought quite as clearly as I could have done if I had spent more time on it, but I think I covered the "practicality" angle when I said, "...the narrowest beam we can practically generate..." That's really the heart of my answer: The OP expressed skepticism that we could hit such a small target with a laser from so far away, and I'm saying that the laser "spot" is a lot bigger than the OP might have imagined.

Answer (score 0):

I will add here that the inevitable spreading of the laser beam both by imperfections in its construction and by beam deflection in the atmosphere are necessary for bouncing a laser off a reflector on the moon, because the reflector is so small (~ one foot) relative to the distance between the moon and earth (240,000 miles) that no mechanical aiming mechanism exists that would allow a laser beam (diameter ~ 1/8th inch) to nail the target and come back.

The best mechanical aiming we can manage (with telescopes) can resolve the width of a dime at a distance of about two miles- in the absence of atmospheric refraction- which isn't good enough for this job.

Answer (score 0):

If a laser beam is projected onto the moon through a telescope, the resulting spot will be the same size as the smallest feature the telescope can resolve in the Moon.

Actually only a very small fraction of the light sent to the moon via laser beam makes its way back to the telescope, so it requires some good signal processing to detect the returning light.  Part of the reason so little light returns is that the retroreflector we have on the moon is much smaller than the size of the projected laser spot.  If it were a perfect retroreflector the same size as the projected beam, we could get back nearly all of the laser light.  But even the Hubble telescope can resolve at best a spot about 85 meters across at that distance;  and making a retroreflector that big and placing it on the moon would be quite a challenge!